Mypy error in Python 3.11 version when I try to use dict[str, str]
I have function defined like this:
def lambda_handler(event: dict[str,str], context:LambdaContext) -> str:

When I run mypy with strict flag, it is complaining that 'dict' is not subscriptable.
I know I can fix this with from typing import Dict and use Dict[str, str] but I want to stick with this syntax dict[str, str].
Is there any possibility to get rid of that mypy error while using the 'new' dict[] syntax? I am using Python v. 3.11.
Many thanks

Try with mypy --python-version 3.11

@MartinGolis Are you sure that mypy runs on Python 3.11 and is not installed on some previous Python runtime? It seems like it should run the same Python version by default.

You can use --python-version option with 3.11 as value. Quoting from the documentation.

--python-version X.Y
This flag will make mypy type check your code as if it were run under
Python version X.Y. Without this option, mypy will default to using
whatever version of Python is running mypy

